# Laravel - json_decode on response::json returns NULL

Tags: json, laravel

However if I do return $response; all the data is perfectly displayed.

It seems like json_decode only works when I call the API via curl but that was when the API was in a separate app on another vhost. I'm re-integrating it into our main app but I'm unable to extract the data.

```
echo $response['error']
echo $response->error
return $response->error
```

none of the above works.

performing a foreach on $response, all I get is header info.

```
foreach ($response as $a)
     {
       echo $a;
     }
```

returns
Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: application/json Date: Fri, 14 Feb 2014 09:24:02 GMT

my controller

```
$response = ApiHelper::getCcm($pid);

    //convert raw json into array
    $ja = json_decode($response,true);

    var_dump($ja);
```

the apihelper

```
return Response::json(array(
    'error' => false,
      'data'  => $data->toArray()
       ),200);
```

Comment: no idea what your problem is. Please re-read your question, and amend to make it clear what the issue is and what outcome you want

Comment: Did you ask any question at all ? I didn't get it.